# Babylon.JS Проблема с глубиной (depth)

Tags: объекты, текстура, babylon.js

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста что надо сделать, чтобы избежать нижеприведенные визуальные артефакты в babylon.js?

[image]

Например в c++/openFrameworks это решается методом ofEnableDepthTest().

Иногда рендерится нормально, иногда нет. Особенно, объекты глючат сами с собой.

Материалы PBRMaterial, c .disableDepthWrite = false;

Что можно попробовать? Вероятно с depth buffer что-то.